# How to write High order function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, higher-order-functions

I am trying to solve this question, on Codewars,
This kata is the first of a sequence of four about "Squared Strings".

You are given a string of n lines, each substring being n characters long: For example:

```
s = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"
```

We will study some transformations of this square of strings.

```
Vertical mirror: vert_mirror (or vertMirror or vert-mirror)
vert_mirror(s) => "dcba\nhgfe\nlkji\nponm"
Horizontal mirror: hor_mirror (or horMirror or hor-mirror)
hor_mirror(s) => "mnop\nijkl\nefgh\nabcd"
or printed:

vertical mirror   |horizontal mirror   
abcd --> dcba     |abcd --> mnop 
efgh     hgfe     |efgh     ijkl 
ijkl     lkji     |ijkl     efgh 
mnop     ponm     |mnop     abcd
```

My Task:
--> Write these two functions

and

--> high-order function oper(fct, s) where

--> fct is the function of one variable f to apply to the string s (fct will be one of vertMirror, horMirror)

Examples:

```
s = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"
oper(vert_mirror, s) => "dcba\nhgfe\nlkji\nponm"
oper(hor_mirror, s) => "mnop\nijkl\nefgh\nabcd"
```

Note:
The form of the parameter fct in oper changes according to the language. You can see each form according to the language in "Sample Tests".

Bash Note:
The input strings are separated by , instead of \n. The output strings should be separated by \r instead of \n.

Here's the code below:

```
def vert_mirror(strng):
# your code
    
def hor_mirror(strng):
    # your code
    pass
def oper(fct, s):
    # your code
    pass
```

"I'Have tried using reverse [::-1] but it doesn't work..

Comment: Is the blocker for you how to implement `vert_mirror()`, `hor_mirror()`, or `oper()`?

Answer (score 1):

The if statement at the bottom is for testing, remove it if you want to use the code somewhere else.

```
def vert_mirror(string):
    rv = []
    separator = '\n'

    words = string.split(separator)

    for word in words:
        rv.append(word[::-1])

    rv = separator.join(rv)

    #return the representation of rv, bc \n will be displayed as a newline
    return repr(rv)
    
def hor_mirror(string):
    rv = []
    separator = '\n'

    words = string.split(separator)

    rv = words[::-1]

    rv = separator.join(rv)

    #return the representation of rv, bc \n will be displayed as a newline
    return repr(rv)


def oper(fct, s):
    return fct(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"
    print(oper(vert_mirror, s))
    print(oper(hor_mirror, s))
```

EDIT: I've just seen the note "The input strings are separated by , instead of \n. The output strings should be separated by \r instead of \n.", if you need to change separators, just change the value of "separator" accordingly.
Or remove the repr(), if you want the raw string.